# バッジ「鑑識眼」の目標進捗状況の日本語訳が誤っている

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

バッジ「鑑識眼」を目標に設定した際に、次のようなツールチップが現れます。

[image: 「鑑識眼」バッジを目標にした際のツールチップ]

このツールチップには、そのバッジの達成条件の進捗がバーで表示されていますが、このうち「合計投票数の25%以上が質問自体への投票」という条件の達成状況のところで「XY/25 割」との表示が観察されます。この表示が「全体の25%」との比較であるならば単位が「割」だと、日本語として不正確になってしまいます。

改善策として「割」の部分の翻訳テキストを「%」に変更できないでしょうか。

---

（追記）

よくみると「質問の XY/25 %」と直しても、まだ「質問の」では日本語として意味が通りませんね。「質問の」も「質問に対する投票の割合」などに文言修正が必要そうです。

---

念のためこのツールチップの出し方を補足しておきます。

1. 自分のユーザページにいく
2. 「アクティビティ」タブの「概要」を表示する
3. 「バッジ」項目の「次の目標」を「鑑識眼」に設定する
4. 「鑑識眼」という文字列をクリックする

この進捗表示がほかの場面でも使用されているかどうかは確認できていません。また類似の条件をもつバッジがある場合、そちらの進捗表示も念のため確認した方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: 対象の Strings は https://ja.traducir.win/strings/8625 で、元の文字列は "`$Percent$/$PercentRequired$ percent on questions`" みたいです。

Comment: `質問が $Percent$/$PercentRequired$%` で如何でしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

対象の string https://ja.traducir.win/strings/8625 の翻訳を更新しました。

- 前：`質問の $Percent$/$PercentRequired$ 割`
- 後：`質問が $Percent$/$PercentRequired$%`

暫く待つと翻訳が反映されるはずです。

Comment: 2024.01.10 新しい翻訳の反映を確認しました。日次程度のバッチかと思ったら、意外ともっとタイムラグがありますね。いずれにしてもご対応ありがとうございました。